# Space generated by a reflection

Tags: general-topology, geometry, differential-geometry

Suppose I embed a mirror (not necessarily plane) in some space (say a manifold). Is there a theory that tells you how to classify the "space" generated by the reflection (the one you see if you were inside the ambient space)? That is, is there a theory of "reflected spaces"? Are there non trivial examples of such simple reflected spaces known?

PS : note that the reflection can be self-similar : http://mathcraft.wonderhowto.com/inspiration/math-craft-inspiration-week-christmas-chaos-0131820/

Comment: old but just in case some links that might help "Spherical, Cubic, and Parabolic Environment Mappings": http://cgvr.cs.uni-bremen.de/teaching/cg_literatur/Spherical,%20Cubic,%20and%20Parabolic%20Environment%20Mappings.pdf   and "The structure of mirrors on Platonic surfaces": https://arxiv.org/pdf/1501.04744.pdf . It might be seen also as a problem on dynamical billiards (the visible surface of the mirror from the point of view of the current viewer is "sewed" to the rest of the space where the mirror was placed): https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1412107/189215